# DataGridView throwing null reference error after code update

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, datagridview

As a fairly new user to `VB.NET`, I thought it was about time I tried to get to grips with `DataGridView` after learning the fundamentals of `ListView` and other basic knowledge. However, I have an error of 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object'. Let me try to explain how I think I have created this error but cannot seem to find a way out.

Initially, I had the code in the 1 winform, **DGVtest.vb** and upon pressing the 'fill grid' button, it filled the grid nulls and all. What I thought I would do to keep the code cleaner and in the long term, have more control, is to move the code out of **DGVtest.vb** and create a module, **DGVmod.vb** and put the code in there. However, being a new user, I now find myself totally out of my depth and looking for assistance as to how to move forward with this.

So, to outline, the DGV is in **DGVtest.vb** with a 'fill grid' button which calls '**DGVmod.fillgrid()**' to fill the grid. If anyone can offer any assistance, I will be very grateful. Many thanks

```
Imports System
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Module DGVmod

    Private da As OleDbDataAdapter
    Private ds As DataSet
    Public dtSource As DataTable

    Private PageCount As Integer
    Private maxRec As Integer
    Private pageSize As Integer
    Private currentPage As Integer
    Private recNo As Integer

    Sub fillPostings()

        Dim conn As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(My.Settings.storageConnectionString)

        'Set the DataAdapter's query.
        da = New OleDbDataAdapter("select * from Postings", conn)
        ds = New DataSet()

        ' Fill the DataSet.
        da.FillSchema(ds, SchemaType.Source, "Postings")
        da.Fill(ds, "Postings")

        ' Set the source table.
        dtSource = ds.Tables("Postings")

    End Sub

    Sub btnprevious()

        If Not CheckFillButton() Then Return

        If currentPage = PageCount Then
            recNo = pageSize * (currentPage - 2)
        End If

        currentPage = currentPage - 1

        'Check if you are already at the first page.
        If currentPage < 1 Then
            MessageBox.Show("You are at the First Page!")
            currentPage = 1
            Return
        Else
            recNo = pageSize * (currentPage - 1)
        End If

        loadpages()

    End Sub

    Sub btnnext()

        'If the user did not click the "Fill Grid" button then Return
        If Not CheckFillButton() Then Return

        'Check if the user clicked the "Fill Grid" button.
        If pageSize = 0 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Set the Page Size, and then click the ""Fill Grid"" button!")
            Return
        End If

        currentPage = currentPage + 1

        If currentPage > PageCount Then
            currentPage = PageCount

            'Check if you are already at the last page.
            If recNo = maxRec Then
                MessageBox.Show("You are at the Last Page!")
                Return
            End If
        End If

        loadpages()

    End Sub

    Sub btnlast()

        If Not CheckFillButton() Then Return

        ' Check if you are already at the last page.
        If recNo = maxRec Then
            MessageBox.Show("You are at the Last Page!")
            Return
        End If

        currentPage = PageCount

        recNo = pageSize * (currentPage - 1)

        loadpages()

    End Sub

    Private Sub DisplayPageInfo()

        DGVtest.txtDisplayPageNo.Text = "Page " & currentPage.ToString & "/ " & PageCount.ToString

    End Sub

    Sub fillgrid()

        Try
            'Set the start and max records. 
            pageSize = CInt(DGVtest.cmbPageSize.Text)
            maxRec = DGVtest.DGV.Rows.Count
            PageCount = maxRec \ pageSize

            ' Adjust the page number if the last page contains a partial page.
            If (maxRec Mod pageSize) > 0 Then
                PageCount = PageCount + 1
            End If

            'Initial seeings
            currentPage = 1
            recNo = 0

            ' Display the content of the current page.
            loadpages()

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.InnerException.ToString)
        End Try

    End Sub

    Private Sub loadpages()

        Dim i As Integer
        Dim startRec As Integer
        Dim endRec As Integer
        Dim dtTemp As DataTable
        'Dim dr As DataRow

        'Duplicate or clone the source table to create the temporary table.

        dtTemp = dtSource.Clone <--- ERROR IS HERE

        If currentPage = PageCount Then
            endRec = maxRec
        Else
            endRec = pageSize * currentPage
        End If

        startRec = recNo

        'Copy the rows from the source table to fill the temporary table.
        For i = startRec To endRec - 1
            dtTemp.ImportRow(dtSource.Rows(i))
            recNo = recNo + 1
        Next

        DGVtest.DGV.DataSource = dtTemp
        DisplayPageInfo()

    End Sub

    Sub btnfirst()

        If Not CheckFillButton() Then Return

        ' Check if you are already at the first page.
        If currentPage = 1 Then
            MessageBox.Show("You are at the First Page!")
            Return
        End If

        currentPage = 1
        recNo = 0

        loadpages()

    End Sub

    Private Function CheckFillButton() As Boolean

        'Check if the user clicks the "Fill Grid" button.
        If pageSize = 0 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Set the Page Size, and then click the ""Fill Grid"" button!")
            CheckFillButton = False
        Else
            CheckFillButton = True
        End If
    End Function

    Sub cmbpage()

        'Set the start and max records. 
        pageSize = CInt(DGVtest.cmbPageSize.Text)
        maxRec = dtSource.Rows.Count
        PageCount = maxRec \ pageSize

        ' Adjust the page number if the last page contains a partial page.
        If (maxRec Mod pageSize) > 0 Then
            PageCount = PageCount + 1
        End If

        'Initial seeings
        currentPage = 1
        recNo = 0

        ' Display the content of the current page.
        loadpages()

    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: If the error is triggered in the line `dtTemp = dtSource.Clone`, it would be because `dtSource` is `null`, that is, this part is reached before `fillPostings()` is called. Just think about the reason for this to happen and perform the fix.

Comment: @varocarbas, So where have I gone wrong. Thanks

Comment: You have to call `fillPostings` before `loadpages`. What sounds pretty logical: don't deal with the contents of the grid before populating it.

Comment: Excellent. I have spent the last 4 hours looking at that. many thanks. If you like to post as answer, I will gladly accept. Happy new year.

Comment: You are welcome (happy new year to you too). I prefer to not write an answer as far as this is not a too-relevant-to-others issue, just a small misunderstanding (you should learn to debug the code and next time will find this out quickly). We can let it as it is (with comments) or you might even delete this question if you wish.